# How to extract Array nested in json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some problem with arrays results in JSON. This is my json file, I would like to extract all the "extlinks" results Arrays, for each object. Any avices? It is the wikipedia API json.

```
Array
(
[continue] => Array
    (
        [eloffset] => 10
        [continue] => ||
    )

[query] => Array
    (
        [normalized] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => rome
                        [to] => Rome
                    )

            )

        [pages] => Array
            (
                [25458] => Array
                    (
                        [pageid] => 25458
                        [ns] => 0
                        [title] => Rome
                        [extlinks] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //dx.doi.org/10.1017%2FS0009840X00221331
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F295257
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Rome¶ms=41_54_N_12_30_E_type:city_region:IT
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20071210175055/http://english.seoul.go.kr/gover/cooper/coo_02sis.html
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20080204030918/http://www.romaperkyoto.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=35&Itemid=52
                                    )

                                [5] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20080508191341/http://www.commune-tunis.gov.tn/fr/mairie_cooperation1.htm
                                    )

                                [6] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20080530094628/http://www.trincoll.edu/depts/rome/curriculum/rome350.html
                                    )

                                [7] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20080613192334/http://www.mpg.de/english/aboutTheSociety/aboutUs/scientificAwards/awardsOfMPS/hannoIlseHahnPrize/index.html
                                    )

                                [8] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20080708234610/http://www.isvroma.it/public/EN/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=+
                                    )

                                [9] => Array
                                    (
                                        [*] => //web.archive.org/web/20130702010825/http://www.krakow.pl/otwarty_na_swiat/2531,kat,0,5,miasta_partnerskie.html
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

My php code is:

```
    $str=file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($str, true);
```

How may I echo all extlinks arrays?

Comment: the json is irrelevant. you're decoding it to a native php object/array structure, and you access it like you would any OTHER nested php object/array structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
<?php

$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=rome&prop=extlinks&format=json";

$str=file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str, true);

$linksArray = [];

// current() takes an array and returns the current value (first in this case)
foreach (current($json['query']['pages'])['extlinks'] as $extlink){

  $pos = strpos($extlink['*'], 'http');

  if($pos == false){
    $linksArray[] = $extlink['*'];
  }
  else{
    $linksArray[] = substr($extlink['*'], 0, $pos);
    $linksArray[] = substr($extlink['*'], $pos);
  }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($linksArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => //dx.doi.org/10.1017%2FS0009840X00221331
    [1] => //dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F295257
    [2] => //tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Rome¶ms=41_54_N_12_30_E_type:city_region:IT
    [3] => //web.archive.org/web/20071210175055/
    [4] => http://english.seoul.go.kr/gover/cooper/coo_02sis.html
    [5] => //web.archive.org/web/20080204030918/
    [6] => http://www.romaperkyoto.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=35&Itemid=52
    [7] => //web.archive.org/web/20080508191341/
    [8] => http://www.commune-tunis.gov.tn/fr/mairie_cooperation1.htm
    [9] => //web.archive.org/web/20080530094628/
    [10] => http://www.trincoll.edu/depts/rome/curriculum/rome350.html
    [11] => //web.archive.org/web/20080613192334/
    [12] => http://www.mpg.de/english/aboutTheSociety/aboutUs/scientificAwards/awardsOfMPS/hannoIlseHahnPrize/index.html
    [13] => //web.archive.org/web/20080708234610/
    [14] => http://www.isvroma.it/public/EN/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=+
    [15] => //web.archive.org/web/20130702010825/
    [16] => http://www.krakow.pl/otwarty_na_swiat/2531,kat,0,5,miasta_partnerskie.html
)
```

Comment: this is the original json https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=rome&prop=extlinks&format=json

Comment: Thank you, this works but results for each object are chained. Inside the Json the extlinks results are successive, or "chained". Do you think it is possible to get one per line?

Comment: Look at the last row:     [9] => //web.archive.org/web/20130702010825/http://www.krakow.pl/otwarty_na_swiat/2531,kat,0,5,miasta_partnerskie.html
 there are two urls chained

Comment: @EVEMilano Ok, I edited the answer to achieve that behavior. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need. The code is ok for thequery "rome", for other queries the numeric value changes. What if I want to skip the value ['25458']? It change for every query so I don't know this value :(

Comment: @EVEMilano edited again ;) you can use `current()` for that. It got a bit ugly now, but works fine. You can put the result of current in a variable to see it easier, and the access to ['extlinks'] in that variable and loop over it, but this way it takes only one line.
Please, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @EVEMilano Ok, glad for it! Please, don't forget to always accept the right answer to support the users motivation :)